# How can I change my system path for Python on a Mac?

Tags: python, pythonpath

I have a problem regarding Pythonpath.

When I print the contents of sys.path the system version appears before the Macports version. How can I change the path such that the macports version appears before the system version permanently, I don't want to reverse the path in the beginning of each program. If you're interested this is the whole path:

```
['', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyglet-1.1.4-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/greenlet-0.3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cocos2d-0.4.0-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/simplejson-2.1.6-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyObjC', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:  sys.path.append("the new path here")

Comment: That doesn't work because when I restart Python the path remains the same as before unless I'm missing out on something...

Comment: /usr/local/lib/python/site-packages (change it according to your python dir)

Put a path file (.pth) in that directory.
path files are just simple files with one library path per line.